# Help needed, apex visualforce tabs stops working when I add link href and script src

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

My visualforce apex tabs and the picklists I have in them stop working if I add these lines below . Iam need to add tagging system for search, so I found this jQuery plugin but it is creating issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Lines that are creating issue:

````
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script> ```
````

Comment: You should consider using static resources to load your CSS instead of CDNs

Comment: Can you guide me how do I proceed to add these 3 links as static resource, just by downloading and adding them as static resource will do??

Answer (score 1):

CDNs are not recommended by Salesforce instead you should use static resources by going to **Setup -> Static Resources** and upload each CSS individually or all in a folder. Then use the following syntax to load the scripts.

```
<ltng:require 
    styles="{!$Resource.jsLibraries  + '/styles/jsMyStyles.css'}"
    scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
```

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm